# GWT 2.6.1 Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.GWTShell

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-hosted-mode, gwt-dev-mode

I am trying to execute a sample application built on GWT 2.6.1 and when I click on app.gwt.xml and say "Run as" -> "GWT Hosted Mode Application", immediately the console prints "Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.GWTShell"..

As far as the answers that I gathered about this issue is, GWT compiler is looking to read the gwt-dev-windows.jar which is not part of GWT 2.6.1 and I do have gwt-dev.jar in my classpath too.

Can someone suggest me how to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 2):

`GWTShell` was [removed in GWT 2.5.1](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_5_1_RC1). You should use `com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode` instead as your main class. Please see [Google Plugin for Eclipse's documentation](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/running_and_debugging_2_0) for more information.

Comment: Removed in 2.5.1, and deprecated [since 1.6](https://web.archive.org/web/20120310162302/http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/ReleaseNotes_1_6.html) ! (and 1.6 was released in April 2009 !)

Comment: Thank you so much for the info. So far I was creating a new configuration for "GWT hosted Mode Application" and that automatically pulls my app and the class specified in entry point. My organization's policy is not allowing us to add googlr Plugin. Is there any other way to manually specify DevMode..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Google Plugin for Eclipse fails to detect the version of GWT you're using and (incorrectly IMO) falls back to legacy mode (which could almost be called "legacy legacy" now that we have SuperDevMode).

That was a known issue with 2.6.0 but 2.6.1 should have "fixed" it. You might have to update your Google Plugin for Eclipse, or try manually changing the main class to `com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode`.